# Firefox svg rendering: how to get real g position?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, cross-browser

I have a page with a svg loaded via object.

Then, I call a function that loads a div, using width, height, left and top of an internal g element

```
var cartina = document.getElementById(whatMap);
        var cartinaContext;         
        cartina.addEventListener("load",function(){
        cartinaContext = cartina.contentDocument;
        var el   = $("#mappaBase", cartinaContext)[0]; 
        var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect(); 
        var whatContainer = "#containerIcone"+whatMap;
        $(whatContainer).css("position", "absolute");
        $(whatContainer).width(rect.width);
        $(whatContainer).height(rect.height);
        $(whatContainer).css("left", rect.left);
        $(whatContainer).css("top", rect.top);
}
```

I'm using getBoundingClientRect(). I'm applying the div #containerIcone over the svg. 
In Chrome it works smoothly well. The problem is in Firefox: when I load the page, width and height are properly loaded but left and top are not. If I inspect the svg with Firefox, it appears that the g element is placed in a fixed position, while the *rendered* g element has another one (responsive to window dimensions and other elements position). Still, the g fixed element reacts well to window various sizes. The div is placed over the g element fixed inspect-position.

Inspecting the same element with Chrome reveals that the g element inspect box is drawed everytime where the g rendered element is.

How can I make this work in Firefox?

Comment: Best provide a complete testcase with markup as a stack snippet (or if not a jsfiddle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, it's working cross-browser.
Instead of positioning with .top and .left of the nested g element, I get width and height of nested element

```
var el   = $(nestedElement); 
var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
```

Then I get width and height of the parent svg element

```
var rectSvg = mysvg.getBoundingClientRect();
```

Then I subtract the **el** width and height from the **svg** ones, and divide results by 2. The final result is the white space the svg has inside it, top and left, used to center the rendered element **el** inside the **svg** element (used by browser to mantain aspect ratio). Then I apply those results as css top and left of my div containing icons - it will be positioned exactly over the g **el** element.

```
var leftSpace = (rectSvg.width - rect.width)/2;
var topSpace = (rectSvg.height - rect.height)/2;
$(myPositionedDiv).css("left", leftSpace);
$(myPositionedDiv).css("top", topSpace);
```

This manner, however Firefox positions the element despite of rendering, left and top are correctly calculated.